# node.js XmlHttpRequest opens localhost:1337 why and how to solve?

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I want to grab data from a website every 15 minutes and save it in a database. The code nodejs 
    with XmlHttpRequest works but is also opening website localhost:1337 (with error not availiable and
    permission denied).
    question, why is the website opened, and can I solve it?
    are there perhaps other possiblities to grab data from website, for instance if data changes on 
    website then nodejs receives marks that wbsite changed and runs?

```
My code:
---
var XMLHttpRequest = require('node-http-xhr');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var request = require("request");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost", user: "pieter", password: "XXX", database: "test"
});
console.log('Testing');
setInterval(function () {

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var body = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(body.dht22.temperature);
    var sql = "INSERT INTO weerdata( binnentemp,binnenvocht, luchtdruk, buitentemp, buitenvocht) 
    Values (" + body.dht22.temperature + "," + body.dht22.humidity + "," + body.dht22.pressure + "," 
    + body.dataWV.tempPJ + "," + body.dataWV.lvPJ + ")";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
        });
    }
};
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://192.168.192.36/json', true);
xmlhttp.send();
}, 90000);

---
```